# Connect Visual Studio to MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, visual-studio-2013, mysql-workbench

Hello I have Visual Studio 2013 Express and MySQL Workbench installed. I am trying to add a local database connection to MySQL to open a .mwb file within [Visual Studio (Link to see screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mulgH.png). I have tried the MySQL connection tool (mysql-connector-net-6.9.8.msi) and Visual Studio still fails to recognize MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will never work, as both Visual Studio and MySQL Workbench are clients to MySQL Server. Instead, connect both to the same MySQL Server.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate you taking time out to answer my question